# Awk to filter file based on conditions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

I am using the below piece of code to filter my source file.
This code contains multiple gsub conditions

But here issue is due to multiple gsub, script is taking huge time to execute and parse data in another file.
Could you please me to know other way to implement these conditions so that my script can execute faster

```
awk -F"[        \t]" -v OFS="|" '{gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/,"");gsub(/"/,"");gsub(/[[:blank:]]+|\.|\-/,"",$32);gsub(/[[:blank:]]+|\.|\-/,"",$13);gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:spa
ce:]]+$|\,/,"",$38);gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$|\,/,"",$42);gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$|\,/,"",$44);gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",$27);gsub(/^[[:spa
ce:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",$40);gsub(/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$/,"",$18);
```

Here is the same code, but cut in sections for easier reading (for readability only):

```
awk -F"[        \t]" -v OFS="|" '{gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/,"");
                                  gsub(/"/,"");
                                  gsub(/[[:blank:]]+|\.|\-/,"",$32);
                                  gsub(/[[:blank:]]+|\.|\-/,"",$13);
                                  gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$|\,/,"",$38);
                                  gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$|\,/,"",$42);
                                  gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$|\,/,"",$44);
                                  gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",$27);
                                  gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",$40);
                                  gsub(/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$/,"",$18);
```

Please let me know if input file is required, will share it

Comment: How much time does it take now for how big a file? And how fast would it have to run to be useful to you?

Comment: Congratulations for writing this.  But please explain what it does.  Each gsub has a particular purpose, which we do not know.   Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Knowing the purpose or objective, we might be able to suggest something else to get the same result, faster.  A sample input file (not the super big file, something to illustrate the requirement) would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Jas,
Input file is around 400MB and it is taking 2-3 hours.
Need a way by which i can execute by 20-25 minutes.

Comment: Rewrite using a "better" language.  Better in terms of speed.  I have used perl scripts to replace bash ones with surprising results.

Comment: @as7951: Post a snippet of your input file and show us what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an anwser, but a readable version of your code:

```
awk -F"[        \t]" -v OFS="|" '
  { gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/,"");
    gsub(/"/,"");  
    gsub(/[[:blank:]]+|\.|\-/,"",$32);
    gsub(/[[:blank:]]+|\.|\-/,"",$13);
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$|\,/,"",$38);
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$|\,/,"",$42);
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$|\,/,"",$44);
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",$27);
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",$40);
    gsub(/^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$/,"",$18);
  }' # closing brace and quote were probably missing
```